# Deterministic Finite Automata question

Tags: formal-languages, automata-theory

I am very new to finite automata, and I came across an issue in my professors lecture slides which I think is wrong, and I'd wonder if any of you could confirm:
Alphabet: {1}

[Automata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZoEj.png)

Surely the accepting language is not this, and is rather

{x: x (iselementof) StarClosureAlphabet and the length of x is even}

If this is incorrect and you can explain, please do, I really can't understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should say "*the length of* $x$ is even," not "$x$ is even."